# how to convert python time.time() to date format for sql insertion

Tags: python, sql, date, cx-oracle

I have the following script:

```
import time
start = time.time()
end = time.time()
runtime = end - start
```

I am trying to insert the start, end, and runtime variables into a database table. I am currently getting

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

this is because start and end are integers and I need them to be in a date format.

my attempt was to convert it this way:

```
start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but this is not working. I would like to use the variables start and end and convert them to an appropriate format using the time module.

Comment: Please specify the sql connector you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `datetime` instead

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now() # Type: datetime.datetime
end = datetime.now() # Type: datetime.datetime
runtime = end - start
runtime.total_seconds() # Type: float
```

Edit: Using the `time` module:

```
import time
start = time.time()
end = time.time()
start_as_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(start))
end_as_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(end))
```

In case you prefer it as a `time.struct_time`, then you can add

```
start_as_struct = time.strptime(start_as_str , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_as_struct = time.strptime(end_as_str , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, if you want it as datetime, then you will need to use the first module

Comment: "using the time module."

Comment: @syrkull answer updated, let me know if this is what you are looking for